# how to find object field and update with the my variable javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, lodash

I want to update field in json.
My field is selectedCIID, this field is inside the some object with some hierarchy,

rows->panels->target->selectedCIId,

```
  var dashboard = results.dashboard;
  var dashboardJson = angular.fromJson(dashboard);
  //dashboardJson.rows //dashboardJson.rows[0].panels
  var j;
  for(i=0; i<=dashboardJson.rows; i++){
    for(j=0;)
    dashboardJson.rows[i].panels
    dashboardJson.rows[0].panels[0].targets[0].selectedCIID = ci;
    //dashboardJson.rows[0].panels[0].targets[0].selectedCIID
  }
```

JSON:

```
{
    "rows": [{
        "title": " row 1",
        "panels": [{
            "targets": [{
                "selectedCIID": "5856742957ce424b8db6cfb309b6b013",
                "series": ""
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "title": "row 2",
        "panels": [{
            "targets": [{
                "selectedCIID": "5856742957ce424b8db6cfb309b6b013",
                "series": ""
            }]
        }, {
            "targets": [{
                "selectedCIID": "5856742957ce424b8db6cfb309b6b013",
                "series": ""
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Code above is just dummy code for showing my approach.
I can do this using native JS code. for loop.

But if I can use lodash for iterating this object _each or something it will be fine.

Or

How can I write the code to find selectedCIID inside panels wherever this field is coming updated with the my variable.

I want to update "selectedCIID" field.
Please help me..

Comment: It's fine just a problem in condition(`i<=dashboardJson.rows`) remove equality `=` check from this condition as you are starting from 0 index not 1;

Comment: yes. I got it. this just and example.. can you suggest me same way to do in lodash..

Comment: Try this [Loop through properties in JavaScript object with Lodash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310946/loop-through-properties-in-javascript-object-with-lodash)

Comment: I want to find key and want to update in all the places, that key can come many time..

Comment: You can update key value for current row iterating;

Comment: updated my question please see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106884/discussion-between-itzmukeshy7-and-javascript-coder).

Comment: can we continue the discussion.. please

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the property of all `targets` then multiple loops can do this.

```
var rowI, panelI, targetI,
    rows, panels, targets, target;

rows = dashboardJson.rows;
for (rowI = 0; rowI < rows.length; rowI++) {
    panels = rows[rowI].panels;

    for (panelI = 0; panelI < panels.length; panelI++) {
        targets = panels[panelI].targets;

        for (targetI = 0; targetI < targets.length; targetI++) {
            target = targets[targetI];
            target.selectedCIID  = ci;
        }   
    }   
}
```

You can also add some `if` statements, in case you want to filter desired `rows`, `panels`, `targets`